# Testing an IConnectableObservable with the TestScheduler

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Ok, it's late but I can't for the life of me work out why the following is happening.

I am trying to test the following (simplified) `IConnectableObservable<long>`:

```cs
private const int PollingIntervalMinutes = 5;

private IConnectableObservable<long> CreateObservable(IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(PollingIntervalMinutes), scheduler)
        .StartWith(0)
        .Publish();
}
```

If I test it "long hand" as follows the test passes:

```cs
[Test]
public void ShouldReturnExpectedNumberOfMessagesLongHand()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var observed = scheduler.CreateObserver<long>();

    var observable = CreateObservable(scheduler);

    observable.Subscribe(observed);

    observable.Connect();

    Assert.That(observed.Messages.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));

    scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(PollingIntervalMinutes).Ticks);

    Assert.That(observed.Messages.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));

    scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(PollingIntervalMinutes).Ticks);

    Assert.That(observed.Messages.Count, Is.EqualTo(3));

    scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(PollingIntervalMinutes).Ticks);

    Assert.That(observed.Messages.Count, Is.EqualTo(4));
}
```

However, if I use the `TestScheduler.Start` approach - as follows - the test hangs and never reaches the `Assert`:

```cs
[Test]
public void ShouldReturnExpectedNumberOfMessages()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    var observable = CreateObservable(scheduler);

    var observed = scheduler.Start(() => { observable.Connect(); return observable; }, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(PollingIntervalMinutes * 3).Ticks);

    Assert.That(observed.Messages.Count, Is.EqualTo(4));
}
```

By placing a breakpoint in the observable (i.e. on an additional `Select` or `Do`) I can see that the call to `scheduler.Start` is causing the underlying observable to spin (i.e. hits the breakpoint thousands of times) instead of respecting the scheduled times.

I've tried various different means of calling `Connect` on the `IConnectableObservable` (i.e. connecting prior to calling start, scheduling a call to Connect in the TestScheduler, etc) but to no avail.

It is definitely related to testing an IConnectableObservable as removing the `Publish` (i.e. making it a normal cold observable) makes the test pass.

A sanity check and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The Undisposed Publisher* strikes again.

The usual suspects:

```
var observable = CreateObservable(scheduler);    
scheduler.Start(() => { observable.Connect(); return observable; }, ...
```

To actually dispose of the interval timer, you need a way to dispose the subscription from `observable.Connect()`, and not the subscription by the `Start` method.

Once you connect, your interval is cranking out items (as fast as it can) using the test scheduler, and the unsubscribe doesn't actually do anything, leaving it running - and the test scheduler will never complete.

One way of ensuring the disposal of resources, in general, is to use `Using`.

```
scheduler.Start(() => Observable.Using(() => observable.Connect(), _ => observable), ...
```

But a simpler way of ensuring that the original connection to publish is disposed when the downstream observable is unsubscribed from, is to use `RefCount`.

```
scheduler.Start(() => CreateObservable(scheduler).RefCount(), ...
```

Comment: Of course... not unsubscribing from subscription to the Interval so it's running "forever" (in virtual time). Great answer, thanks.